# How to find the corresponding link for a part of a website?

Tags: javascript, html, web

Given an page web in which we have an application turning on, is there a way to find a link which gives directly the application in a new page without taking in account the other stuffs in the website.

For example can we find a link to the application line -segment in this website: http://www.mathopenref.com/linesegment.html?
The answer is yes here it is :http://www.mathopenref.com/common/appletframe.html?applet=linesegment&wid=600&ht=300

My question is: can we do this true in general? . I'm concerned about the application  Wealth Report presented in the website: https://www.worldwealthreport.com/

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example that you have provided and the other website that you are looking at are very different.
In the first example, the interactive portion that you are linking to is an embedded content that (sort of) has its own independent existence.
But the other website doesnt contain such embedded content. The map that is there in the link is (sort of) built into the page itself. Hence what you are asking is not possible for this one.
There is no "general" rule regarding this. If you are using Firefox, you can check by doing a right-click on that particular content and checking if the "This frame.." option is there or not (In the first example it will come up, will not for the second one). If it is there, then select "Open frame in new tab" and get the address from the address bar.